# OpenMP, R and MacOS

Tags: r, gcc, clang, openmp

so I try to run a package called BTYDplus
when I load it I got this warning

`This data.table install has not detected OpenMP support. It will work but slower in single threaded mode.`

I could run it without OpenMP but it is very slow, so I tried to install openMP by following this tutorial
http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/
but I stuck at `Enabling R to Compile Code with OpenMP on OS X` part specifically when I try to run `vim ~/.R/Makevars/`. It resulted with `"~/.R/Makevars/" Illegal file name`.

any suggestion on how to tell R to use GCC ?

Comment: `"~/.R/Makevars/"` would be a folder, not a file. Maybe it should be without the trailing `/`?

Comment: @rosscova I just tried it, I made a folder .R and make a file called Makevars. after that I enter the configuration. but no luck :(

Comment: Are you sure the `.R` folder wasn't already there? It's hidden, but I think it should be part of a regular installation of R (someone please correct me if I'm wrong here?)

Comment: `"it is very slow"` That surprises me. I still use 1.9.6, which does not provide OpenMP support, and it is far from slow.

Comment: Try following the instructions [by the data.table maintainers](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: @rosscovaIt's from the link that roland provided I got the impression that it might not exist. `likely you need to create the .R directory and the file Makevars in it if it doesn't already exist.`

Comment: @Roland hmm, maybe it is very slow because i use 500 chain for markov ?
I have tried to follow the instruction on the link you provided. but no luck.

Comment: I fail to see how a Markov chain is related to package data.table and how enabling OpenMP within data.table would help with its performance. You should benchmark to see if data.table is your actual bottleneck, which I seriously doubt.

Comment: @Roland any tips on how to do that ?

Comment: `help("Rprof")`

Comment: It would still be interesting to find out what is wrong here. I followed the instruction on the data.table GitHub mentioned by @Roland, but get the same warning on loading the package..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using clang to compile OpenMP code you will need `libomp`. I found the easiest way to get it is through homebrew with `brew install libomp`.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is possible to get openmp compilation working on a Mac Sierra by updating clang (not sure if newer versions of MacOS have fixed this by updating clang) as in [Enable OpenMP support in clang in Mac OS X (sierra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra?rq=1)
it is also possible to get Apple's default clang to work.  Simple add the following to `~/.R/Makevars`

```
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS=-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp
```

This takes advantage of [special CXX/CFLAGS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support) R packages ought to use when compiling OpenMP packages, and that

> Apple Clang does allow you to process the OpenMP pragmas with -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp, and then you can manually link to the OpenMP library.

More details [here](https://iscinumpy.gitlab.io/post/omp-on-high-sierra/).