# Enable OpenMP support in clang in Mac OS X (sierra & Mojave)

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, openmp

I am using Mac OS X Sierra, and I found that clang (LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)) does not support OpenMP:
when I run `clang -fopenmp program_name.c`, I got the following error:

`clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`

It seems that clang does not support `-fopenmp` flag.

I could not find any openmp library in homebrew. According to LLVM website, LLVM already supports OpenMP. But I could not find a way to enable it during compiling.

Does this mean that the default clang in Mac does not support OpenMP?
 Could you provide any suggestions?

(When I switch to GCC to compile the same program (gcc is installed using `brew install gcc --without-multilib`), and the compilation is successful.)

Comment: Indeed, Apple-provided clang does not support OpenMP.

Comment: `brew install llvm` should install the latest LLVM version, i.e. 4.0.0. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: Apple-provided clang does not support OpenMP *by default*. It is possible to enable the feature in Apple-provided clang and also possible to install a more recent version of clang that does support OpenMP by default.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic How do we enable it? do we just need to compile and install the openmp runtime?

Comment: @MarcusJ you should just need to `brew install llvm libomp` and then make sure to use the new clang to compile with the `-fopenmp` flag

Answer (score 40):

1. Try using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)'s llvm:

   ```
   brew install llvm
   ```
2. You then have all the llvm binaries in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`.

   Compile the OpenMP Hello World program. Put `omp_hello.c`

   ```
   /******************************************************************************
        * FILE: omp_hello.c
        * DESCRIPTION:
        *   OpenMP Example - Hello World - C/C++ Version
        *   In this simple example, the master thread forks a parallel region.
        *   All threads in the team obtain their unique thread number and print it.
        *   The master thread only prints the total number of threads.  Two OpenMP
        *   library routines are used to obtain the number of threads and each
        *   thread's number.
        * AUTHOR: Blaise Barney  5/99
        * LAST REVISED: 04/06/05
        ******************************************************************************/
        #include <omp.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
        {
        int nthreads, tid;

        /* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
        #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
          {

          /* Obtain thread number */
          tid = omp_get_thread_num();
          printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

          /* Only master thread does this */
          if (tid == 0) 
            {
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
            }

          }  /* All threads join master thread and disband */

        }
   ```

   in a file and use:

   ```
   /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib omp_hello.c -o hello
   ```

   You might also have to set the `CPPFLAGS` with `-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include`.

   The makefile should look like this:

   ```
   CPP = /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
   CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -fopenmp
   LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib

   omp_hello: omp_hello.c
        $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
   ```

### Update

In macOS 10.14 (Mojave) you might get an error like

```
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.1/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/omp.h:118:13: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
```

If this happens, the macOS SDK headers are missing from `/usr/include`. They moved into the SDK itself with [Xcode 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes). Install the headers into `/usr/include` with

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: You may also need `brew install libomp`

Comment: Indeed, with `llvm@8`, I had to install `libomp`

Comment: This resulted in a "missing separator" error for me. Apparently, that means tabs have to be "hard". So I found the "soft" tab and replaced it, and then I got the error: `*** No rule to make target `omp_hello.c', needed by `omp_hello'.  Stop.` Damned if I do, damned if I don't.

Comment: @rocksNwaves The instructions given here are how to compile a file called `omp_hello.c`. Make is telling you that file doesn't exist and it doesn't know what to do. Solution: provide that file.

Comment: @Ed. Thanks for noting, I included the file in my answer.

Comment: This worked for me (macOS 11.4). For future readers, if you that have Xcode installed, you might need to do `xcode-select --install` to install the command line utilities. When you do `brew install llvm`, it will let you know if you need to do this.

Comment: For me the compile command was `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib omp_hello.c `

Answer (score 32):

Other people have given one solution (using Homebrew llvm). You can also use OpenMP with Apple Clang and Homebrew libomp (`brew install libomp`). Just replace a command like `clang -fopenmp test.c` with `clang -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp test.c -lomp`.

Comment: I tried that, but it wouldn't find `omp.h` for inclusion.

Comment: If you are sure you have install libomp under Homebrew, you can ask on the Homebrew forum https://discourse.brew.sh/. In my case, omp.h is installed under /usr/local/Cellar/libomp/10.0.0/include, symlinked to /usr/local/include.

Comment: Is it known why Apple clang requires the `-Xpreprocessor` flag?

Answer (score 15):

MacOS Mojave with CMake

1. Install LLVM with openmp and libomp with brew

   ```
    brew update
    brew install llvm libomp
   ```
2. add include directories and link directories in `CMakeList.txt`

   ```
    include_directories("/usr/local/include" "/usr/local/opt/llvm/include")
    link_directories("/usr/local/lib" "/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib")
   ```
3. run CMake with the new compilers

   ```
    cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++" ..
   ```

The clang version is 7.0.1 at time of writing

Comment: After trying to build Blender on macOS (which has libomp as a dependency) for 3 days, this is the solution that worked for me, though my symptoms were a bit different. For me the compilation completed, but there were linker errors about missing x86_64 symbols from the libomp library.  This worked for Homebrew's GCC 9.1.0 as of this comment.

Comment: Where is the `CMakelists.txt` ? I have at least 6 files named this way.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works for me in Clion and Mac OS 10.14.6

Comment: An improvement on this answer would be to use `brew --prefix llvm` rather than assuming /usr/local/opt/llvm. Something like `execute_process(COMMAND brew --prefix llvm OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_PREFIX)`

Comment: You can add

`set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++")` in `CMakeList.txt`, so you can run cmake without -D

Comment: This is a more modern solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51448364/7604852

Answer (score 0):

## Conda-Based Compilation Environment

Conda uses clang for OSX compilation (umbrella package `cxx-compiler`), but I hit similar issues with using `llvm-openmp` and the `-fopenmp` flag throwing errors. Solution is rather similar to other answers, but I am including here in case others have more exactly this issue.

Specific solution was to include the Conda environment's `include/` directory in the `CFLAGS`, namely:

```
CFLAGS="-I${CONDA_PREFIX}/include"
```

Note, I also needed to add `-lstdc++ -Wl,-rpath ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib -L${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib` when linking, similar to [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/8869#issuecomment-389925059).