# Installing LibTorch on OSX: unsupported option fopenmp

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp, libtorch

I'm trying to follow the instructions (here https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html) to install LibTorch on OSX. I was all going well up until the "make" command, which returned

```
Scanning dependencies of target example-app
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example-app.dir/example-app.cpp.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example-app.dir/example-app.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/example-app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

By the way, in the earlier cmake step, it seems like the compiler Cmake found was the default system compiler on Mac:

```
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra-mojave