# Trying to install rJava but error says JDK is incomplete

Tags: java, r

I'm using `install.packages('rJava', type='source')`to install rJava, but it presents with the following error:

> configure: error: one or more Java tools are missing.
>
> *** JDK is incomplete! Please make sure you have a complete JDK. JRE is *not* sufficient.
>   configure: error: ./configure failed for jri
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava’
>   * restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava’
>
> Warning in install.packages : 
>   installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

I just installed JDK8 so I'm not sure what's going on. 
`javac -version` throws javac 1.8.0_231

`java -version` throws java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)

This guy at [R: rJava package install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing) came up with a solution that I don't even understand since I'm new to this, but it has something to do with `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`and /jre apparently.

Comment: What is the output to `which java` and `echo $PATH` and `echo $JAVA_HOME`?  Also, what is your platform?  It looks like OS X, but it's best if you confirm.

Comment: @JustinGuerin Yes, it's OS X Mojave version 10.14, sorry. Output to `which java` is /usr/bin/java.   Output to `echo $PATH` is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usrlib/jvm/java-8-sun/jre/bin. Output to `echo $JAVA_HOME` is /usrlib/jvm/java-8-sun/jre

Comment: Looks like JAVA_HOME points to a JRE, not the JDK you want and need.  Have a look at the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348940/12357638) to "What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OS X".   Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1170/_index.html.

Comment: @JustinGuerin Thank you for your help, it seems to have solved the issue with Java, but now I'm getting the following error: clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rJava'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava'
* restoring previous '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava'

Comment: Have a look at how this person solved that error.  https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/3 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra-mojave.  I recommend Googling the error message in situations like this.

Comment: Also, please update your question to include the output to `which java`, `echo $PATH` and `echo $JAVA_HOME`, and I'll put an answer below so that people who encounter the same problem in the future can find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JAVA_HOME points to a JRE, not the JDK you want and need. Have a look at the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348940/12357638) to "What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OS X". Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1170/_index.html